# How to input string 2 value at string 1 that has @ at ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add string value from the database to the string with @ as seen at the code below. However, I keep getting an error such as ; expected and I try to find the answer through other post but it does not seem like there is not. Is there any way I can input the value inside the string with @?

Here is the code :

```
string name = bucketName; //the value that I want to put inside the newPolicy at resource part
        // Put sample bucket policy (overwrite an existing policy)
        string newPolicy = @"{ 
""Statement"":[{ 
""Sid"":""PublicReadGetObject"", 
""Effect"":""Allow"", 
""Principal"": ""*"", 
""Action"":[""s3:GetObject""], 
""Resource"":[""arn:aws:s3:::"//the string name value insert here"/*""]}]}";
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: You can use string concatenation, `string.Format` or string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use that string as an input to [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) then you will need to escape the "{" and "}" by writing them as "{{" and "}}" respectively, like this:

```
string name = "XYZ"; //the value that I want to put inside the newPolicy at resource part
                     // Put sample bucket policy (overwrite an existing policy)
string newPolicy = @"{{ 
""Statement"":[{{ 
""Sid"":""PublicReadGetObject"", 
""Effect"":""Allow"", 
""Principal"": ""*"", 
""Action"":[""s3:GetObject""], 
""Resource"":[""arn:aws:s3:::{0}""]}}]}}";

string s = string.Format(newPolicy, name);
```

Whereupon the value of `s` is:

```
{
"Statement":[{
"Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
"Effect":"Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action":["s3:GetObject"],
"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::XYZ"]}]}
```